# In Python (Pandas/Numpy). How to create a column with the max/min value from two independent series?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I need to create a df.column with the max of two other series (these series are not in the dataframe, but they do share the same index). I can't just add them to the dataframe, because they all have the same column names, and it becomes a mess.

The naive first instinct is:

```
df['Max'] = max(a, b)
```

However, as expected this option gives you error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

A solution is:

```
df['Max'] = ""
df.loc[a > b, 'Max'] = a
df.loc[a < b, 'Max'] = b
```

Is it possible to do this more efficiently?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.maximum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html):

```
>>> np.maximum([2, 3, 4], [1, 5, 2])
array([2, 5, 4])
```